# Implement trigger to ensure referential integrity in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to implement a trigger to ensure referential integrity in mysql

> Getting error in mysql workbench:
>
>  **"referencing" is not valid at this position, expecting FOR**

```
create trigger dept_name after insert on Department
referencing new row as nrow
for each row
when (nrow.Deptname not in (
select Deptname
from Instructor)) 
begin
rollback
end;
```

> Relation Department and Instructor:

```
create table Department(
Deptname  varchar(10),
Budget int,
Building varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (Deptname));

create table Instructor(
EmployeeID int,
name varchar(20),
Deptname  varchar(10),
Salary int,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Deptname) REFERENCES Department(Deptname));
```

Comment: What is `referencing` supposed to do? There's no such thing in the MySQL TRIGGER syntax.

Comment: MySQL uses `NEW.columnname` to reference columns in the new row in triggers.

Comment: So how I can implement a trigger to ensure referential integrity?

Comment: But then getting error "when is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier".

Comment: The foreign key ensures referential integrity. You don't need this trigger.

Comment: It's also wrong. It won't let you create a new department, because there aren't any instructors in the department yet.

Comment: `WHEN` should be `IF`.

Comment: And it needs `THEN` before the code that should be run if the condition is true.

Comment: I have a feeling you got the syntax from a database other than MySQL.

Comment: @KushagraAgrawal You should explain more detail about what referential integrity you need to enforce. I would think the foreign key you already have in the `Instructor` table is what you need. It is not clear why you need a trigger.

Comment: It's a question I got from college that I had to use a trigger to ensure referential integrity.